# PHPExcel в строку попадает ложь

Tags: phpexcel

Получаю данные из таблицы, делаю foreach и заношу в таблицу данные:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$i, $row["title"]);
```

Все данные есть, пустых нет, лишних символов нет, проверял на `rawurldecode()` все число. Все поля получаю, а вот название новости и название категории не хочет. В чем может быть проблема?
Может проблема в кодировке windows-1251?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$i, iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $row["title"]));
```